# Getting undefined call to function in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am calling a simple function from a controller:

```
flash('my message');
```

`flash` function is inside a helpers.php file in App\Http

```
function flash($message)
{
    $flash = app('App\Http\Flash');

    return $flash->message($message);
}
```

`flash` function calls a `Flash` object

```
namespace App\Http;

class Flash{

     public function message($message)
     {
            session()->flash('flash_message', $message);
     }
}
```

Composer.json includes:

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
          "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
```

Ran the command - composer dump-autoload

Page is showing - Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\flash()

I've tried so many things!  Even if I add a tiny test function into the helpers.php file I can't use it in controller.
Is this a namespace issue?  I didn't think I had to add a **use xxxx;** at top of controller as the helpers.php is added to autoload and global?

---

EDIT.

I believe that the registering of the helpers.php file is the key here. All I am doing is adding some functions to global file but cannot get to them from my controller.  I added a really simple function to the helpers.php file yet couldn't access it from the controller:  do I need to add anything to the controller in order to be able to use the helpers file?

**I have managed to get this working by including the helpers.php file in the controller method:**

```
include(app_path() . '/helpers.php');
flash('my message');
```

This now allows me to call the function.  So the autoloading is not working!  A little puzzled...

UPDATE.
I had to put the desired function into a class and call the class.  This now works fine.  I just couldn't get the helpers.php to autoload anything.

Answer (score -1):

I would place the helper file in a global position and in your composer.json file:

```json
"files":[
    "app/helper.php"
],
```

In **helper.php**:

```php
function newflash($message)
{
    session()->flash('flash_message', $message);
}
```

Do a `composer dump-autoload`

It's as simple as this.

Now you can call the `newflash()` method from anywhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks - although still got same message.  I placed the "files": declaration one higher in hierarchy...

Comment: Try another method name instead of flash.. Such as newflash() in the helper.php

Comment: Thanks will try when at my machine

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to register your class in the service provider.

Comment: Is this needed for every class created?  Don't do them for eloquent models...  Thanks will try when at my machine

Comment: this isn't want I want... it should be as easy as autoloading a simple php file of functions I can access - see my update above, thanks